# Error during \COPY command in PostgreSQL to import CSV data

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, copy, importerror

Subject: Error during \COPY command in PostgreSQL

Hello,
I am trying to copy data from multiple CSV files into corresponding tables in PostgreSQL database using the \COPY command. However, I am getting a syntax error at the end of the line and near "FROM". I need help. Thanks in advance. Here's my code:

tablequery.sql

```
-- copy data from budgets.csv file into the budgets table
\COPY budgets (budget_id, dt_create, dt_update, dt_value, category, amount)
FROM 'setup/psql/budgets.csv'
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER true, DELIMITER ';');

-- copy data from expenses.csv file into the expenses table
\COPY expenses (ulid_id, dt_create, dt_update, dt_value, amount, description, budget_id, category)
FROM 'setup/psql/expenses.csv'
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER true, DELIMITER ';');

-- copy data from revenues.csv file into the revenues table
\COPY revenues (ulid_id, dt_create, dt_update, dt_value, amount, description)
FROM 'setup/psql/revenues.csv'
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER true, DELIMITER ';');
```

Terminal output :

````
psql:setup/psql/tablequery.sql:61: error: \copy: parse error at end of line
psql:setup/psql/tablequery.sql:63: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: FROM 'setup/psql/budgets.csv'
        ^
psql:setup/psql/tablequery.sql:66: error: \copy: parse error at end of line
psql:setup/psql/tablequery.sql:68: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: FROM 'setup/psql/expenses.csv'
        ^
psql:setup/psql/tablequery.sql:71: error: \copy: parse error at end of line
psql:setup/psql/tablequery.sql:73: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: FROM 'setup/psql/revenues.csv'
```


└── setup
    └── psql
        ├── budgets.csv
        ├── dbquery.sql
        ├── expenses.csv
        ├── revenues.csv
        └── tablequery.sql
````

Comment: From here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) `\copy` cannot span lines. Look at *Tip* under `\copy` for work around.